# Create an array from two arrays using map in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i've created two arrays in reactjs using map. The first one is

```
const hey = portfolioSectorsPie.map(sector => sector.subtotal);
const hello = portfolioSectorsPie.map(sector => sector.percentage)
```

the format of hey = `[22, 23, 25]`
the format of hello = `[22.35, 22.67, 25.90]`
 i want to create an array which have the following format:

```
finalArr = [22, 23, 25]
         (22.35)% (22.67)%, (25.90)%
```

It might be confusing but imagine the array like this `[22(22.35)%, 23(22.67)%, 25(25.90)%]` with the percentages being down of elements of hey. Any ideas?

Comment: `[22(22.35)%, 23(22.67)%, 25(25.90)%]` that's your array and you need to get `[22, 23, 25], [22.35, 22.67, 25.90]` from that array?

Comment: Not clear what it means `[22, 23, 25] (22.35)% (22.67)%, (25.90)%`.Or `[22(22.35)%, 23(22.67)%, 25(25.90)%]`.

Comment: No, i want to create an array containing these two values. Also i want the second value to be under the first value but i couldn't write it properly.

Comment: array will have the element one after another, if you want to show it down in ui then you need to handle that in ui not during array creation.

Comment: ok, i was wondering if there was a way to do that in javascript

Comment: @MayankShukla understands my case. But my case is not able to be implemented in js

Comment: Nice!! Thanks a lot, that is what i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Each can be helpful here.

Check out this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zazuzo/edit?js,console)

```
const hey = [20,40,60]
const hello = [23.4, 23.5, 36.5];

let retArr = [];
hey.forEach( (h, i) =>
  retArr.push(`${h} (${hello[i]})`)
)

console.log(retArr);
```

Comment: Nice one, thanks! But how to show hello down of h like my case?

Comment: @user7334203 I'm not sure what you mean by "show hello down of h". Could you elaborate? I'd be happy to help.

Comment: @user7334203: Here you go -- https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/qycLzbxu/ :)